# lookup string values in lookup table to populate second dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, vlookup

I have two dataframes, `main_df`:

```
  | header_1
0 | value_1
1 | value_2
2 | value_3
3 | value_1
```

And a lookup dataframe `lookup_df`:

```
  | header_1 | header_2
0 | value_1 | lookup_value_1
1 | value_2 | lookup_value_2
2 | value_3 | lookup_value_3
3 | value_4 | lookup_value_4
```

The values in `main_df` are not unique. The values in `lookup_df' are unique.

I simply want to populate a new column in `main` df with the corresponding  `lookup_value` from `lookup_df`.

Have tried various approaches including `.merge`, `.join`, `.map` and `.lookup`.

```
main_df = pd.merge(main_df, lookup_df, how='inner', on=['header_1'])
```

The outcome I am looking for is:

```
  | header_1 | header_2
0 | value_1 | lookup_value_1
1 | value_2 | lookup_value_2
2 | value_3 | lookup_value_3
3 | value_1 | lookup_value_1
```

Comment: I think you need `main_df['header_2'] = main_df['header_1'].map(lookup_df.set_index('header_1')['header_2'])`

Comment: perhaps you want to do a left merge? `main_df = pd.merge(main_df, lookup_df, how='left', on=['header_1'])`

Comment: @jezrael I tried this but I got the error `InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects`, my lookup values are not unique.

Comment: @joshi123 - what happens if data are not unique in `lookup_df`? Can you edit question?

Comment: @EdChum, the left merge results in a dataframe with all rows from both frames, I only want the 4 rows in the original `main_df`

Comment: @joshi123 - It is problem if want use `map` or `merge` by not unique `lookup_df`. You need uniqueness. One possible solution is [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html).

Comment: @jezrael apologies, had not realised my lookup table was not unique. It should actually be unique so will edit the `lookup_df` and try the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by `Series`:

```
main_df['header_2'] = main_df['header_1'].map(lookup_df.set_index('header_1')['header_2'])
print (main_df)
  header_1        header_2
0  value_1  lookup_value_1
1  value_2  lookup_value_2
2  value_3  lookup_value_3
3  value_1  lookup_value_1
```

Or a bit faster is convert `Series` [`to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_dict.html):

```
main_df['header_2'] = main_df['header_1'].map(lookup_df.set_index('header_1')['header_2']
                                                       .to_dict())
print (main_df)
  header_1        header_2
0  value_1  lookup_value_1
1  value_2  lookup_value_2
2  value_3  lookup_value_3
3  value_1  lookup_value_1
```

**Timings**:

```
#[400000 rows x 1 columns]
main_df = pd.concat([main_df]*100000).reset_index(drop=True)

In [139]: %timeit pd.merge(main_df, lookup_df, how='left', on=['header_1'])
10 loops, best of 3: 73.1 ms per loop

In [140]: %timeit main_df['header_1'].map(lookup_df.set_index('header_1')['header_2'])
10 loops, best of 3: 35.7 ms per loop

In [141]: %timeit main_df['header_1'].map(lookup_df.set_index('header_1')['header_2'].to_dict())
10 loops, best of 3: 35.1 ms per loop
```

EDIT:

You need unique values of column `header_1` in `lookup_df`, one possible solution is [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
print (lookup_df)
  header_1        header_2
0  value_1  lookup_value_1
1  value_2  lookup_value_2
2  value_3  lookup_value_3
3  value_1  lookup_value_4

#keep first value, default parameter keep='first'
lookup_df = lookup_df.drop_duplicates(['header_1'])
print (lookup_df)
  header_1        header_2
0  value_1  lookup_value_1
1  value_2  lookup_value_2
2  value_3  lookup_value_3

#keep last value
lookup_df1 = lookup_df.drop_duplicates(['header_1'], keep='last')
print (lookup_df1)
  header_1        header_2
0  value_1  lookup_value_1
1  value_2  lookup_value_2
2  value_3  lookup_value_3
```

Comment: I edit answer with creating unique `lookup_df`, please check it.

Comment: tested the `drop_duplicates` code and it works, thanks v much

Answer (score 1):

You have to do a merge without the 'how' keyword. Like so:

```
main_df = pd.DataFrame([{'header_1': 'value_1'},{'header_1': 'value_2'},{'header_1': 'value_3'},{'header_1': 'value_1'}])

lookup_df = pd.DataFrame([{'header_1':'value_1', 'header_2':'lookup_value_1'}, {'header_1':'value_2', 'header_2':'lookup_value_2'}, {'header_1':'value_3', 'header_2':'lookup_value_3'}, {'header_1':'value_4', 'header_2':'lookup_value_4'}])

main_df = pd.merge(main_df, lookup_df, on='header_1')
```

The output is

```
  header_1        header_2
0  value_1  lookup_value_1
1  value_1  lookup_value_1
2  value_2  lookup_value_2
3  value_3  lookup_value_3
```